# How to convert a string to an EObject?

Tags: java, emf

I am trying to convert a string to an EObject as :

```
SimpleAnyType wrapper = XMLTypeFactory.eINSTANCE.createSimpleAnyType();
wrapper.setInstanceType(EcorePackage.eINSTANCE.getEString());
wrapper.setValue("Test");
```

Now, I ve got an object of SimpleAnyType. How to convert this to an EObject please explain.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleAnyType extends AnyType, AnyType extends EObject. So you already have your EObject.